# How can i authenticate the twitter user?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am an absolute beginner on Twitter API. I want redirect user to login dialog page and authenticate the user.
I am looking for an sample code which authenticate twitter user and i could not find any. 
And i think Twitter documentation isn't so good.

```
require 'twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php';

$consumer_key = 'xxx';
$consumer_secret = 'xxx';
$access_token = 'myUserID-xxx';
$access_tokan_secret = 'xxx';


$twitter = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $access_token, $access_tokan_secret);

$twitter->post('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=some post');
```

Even if anybody different from me runs this code it posts to my timeline as it should be. Because this is admin's access token and there is myUserID. So, how can i redirect user to login page which asks for some permissions? 
Read, Write and Access direct messages section is selected in my app settings.

Answer (score 0):

For list of twitter libraries: 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries

Personally, I've successfully used the tmhOAuth library for PHP: https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth

Check out oauth_authorize_flow.php for good example of the OAuth flow you are trying to produce: https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuthExamples/blob/master/web/oauth_authorize_flow.php